# MAUI Android app crashes on launch - caused by FileSystem reference

Tags: android, crash, maui

I've created the standard MAUI "Hello World" app targeting Android using Visual Studio 2022.
I compile the default, unmodified code in release mode and generate a signed APK which installs and runs without issue on my Samsung Android tablet.

However, if I then insert the following single line of code into the OnCounterClicked routine, and recompile, the app crashes immediately on launch.  The code doesn't even get a chance to run as I never get the opportunity to click the button.

string path = FileSystem.Current.AppDataDirectory;

What could be causing the crash please?

Thanks!

I expected the app to launch and behave as it had before the FileSystem reference was introduced.

This code works:

```
private void OnCounterClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            count++;

    if (count == 1)
        CounterBtn.Text = $"Clicked {count} time"; 
    else
        CounterBtn.Text = $"Clicked {count} times";  

    SemanticScreenReader.Announce(CounterBtn.Text);
}
```

This code causes the application to crash immediately:

```
private void OnCounterClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string stPath = FileSystem.Current.AppDataDirectory;

            count++;

    if (count == 1)
        CounterBtn.Text = $"Clicked {count} time"; 
    else
        CounterBtn.Text = $"Clicked {count} times";  

    SemanticScreenReader.Announce(CounterBtn.Text);
}
```

I've tried wrapping the above in a try catch block but it still crashes on launch.

Comment: I doubt this line is causing the crash since a button click event would not be run on startup. Try deleting the obj/bin folders and rebuild in release mode.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the actual problem was something else, not related to the question. Therefore, this question is unlikely to be useful to others in the future.

Comment: I'd disagree that this couldn't help others.  If your app is crashing immediately on launch after changing a single line of code then deleting the obj/bin folders and rebuilding is a good potential fix.